# Ударение в словах

Tags: ударение

Почему пОвесть - пОвестей, а нОвость - новостЕй?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: повестЕй, поэтому слова "повесть" и "новость" принадлежат к одному акцентному классу. Хотя вариант пОвестей встречается в обыденной речи и в поэзии,  он является отклонением от нормы.